# Delete and undo in Git

Tags: git

Unless the code you plan on deleting in your Git repository is some "hello world" test code, is there really ever a reason why you would ever want to delete anything you've pushed to the repository?

Does Git have an undo feature that allows you to undo merges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there really ever a reason why you would ever want to delete anything you've pushed to the repository?

Yes, mistakes do happen. As long as nobody else has started working on what you've pushed there's no reason not to replace it. You should check with your peers first though that they're ok with you force pushing.

> Does Git have an undo feature that allows you to undo merges?

`git reset --hard HEAD^` will remove the last commit made to your current branch, and also reset the working tree. This works for merges as well as normal commits.

Comment: Is reset the same thing as revert? In my intelliJ IDE, I only see revert.

Comment: No, `revert` adds a new commit that is the reverse of the commit you're reverting. `reset` moves your current branch to a new commit, and can thus be used to remove commits from the history.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason to delete code is if somebody accidentally added something sensitive to the git repo... secret keys and confidential documents and the like...